# Array error in PHP While migrating image in PHP

Tags: php

I got this error when I'm trying to migrate my image from Prestashop to Opencart using PHP.  Can  anyone here helps me? How can I fix the error?

It seems like the array have a problem. Any suggestions thanks.

```
 <?php
    class ControllerToolMigrate extends Controller {
        public function index() {
            $this->load->model('catalog/product');
            $filter_data = array(
                'start'=> 0,
                'limit'=> 5
            );     
            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductsImage($filter_data);   
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                foreach($result as $sub_product){
                    $str = $sub_product['id_image'];
                    $arr1 = str_split($str);
                    $arr2 = str_split($str,2);
                    print_r($arr1);
                    print_r($arr2);       
                    $link = '';
                    echo $str;
                    foreach($arr1 as $id){
                        $com = array($id);      
                        $link .= $com[0] .'/';
                    }
                    $link .= $str; 
                    echo var_dump ($link);
                    echo $link;  
                    $newLink = 'http://localhost/onlinestore/img/p/'.$link.'-large_default.jpg';

                    //Get the file
                    $content = file_get_contents($newLink);
                    //Store in the filesystem.
                    $fp = fopen("../upload/image/catalog/demo/p/".$str."-large_default.jpg", "w");
                    fwrite($fp, $content);
                    fclose($fp);
                }       
            }
            //Get the file
            /*$content = file_get_contents("http://www.tImOLI12t.my/onlinestore/img/p/9/9-large_default.jpg");
            //Store in the filesystem.
            $fp = fopen("../upload/image/catalog/demo/p/large_default.jpg", "w");
            fwrite($fp, $content);
            fclose($fp);*/
        }
    }
```

[image: Here's my error]

Comment: Can you post the data inside your result?

Comment: id_image probably doesn't exist in your array.